# ODBC Excel driver SQL mapping multiple foreign ids to the same table

Tags: sql, excel

I have a table where 4 columns contains ID values from a second table that represents a pair (`ID`,`TERM`). For instance:

Table1:

```
KEYID | ID1 | ID2 | ID3 | ID4
```

Table2:

```
ID | TERM
```

Is there any way to create an SQL query that provides for instance a table like:

```
KEYID | TERM_ID1 | TERM_ID2 | TERM_ID3 | TERM_ID4
```

where `TERM_ID1`, `TERM_ID2`, `TERM_ID3` and `TERM_ID4` are the corresponding values of the `TERM` column in `Table2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could so something simple like this. It `joins` to `table2` once for each corresponding value and uses the `Term` in the final `select`;

```
SELECT
     t1.KeyID
    ,t2.Term Term_ID1
    ,t3.Term Term_ID2
    ,t4.Term Term_ID3
    ,t5.Term Term_ID4
FROM Table1 t1
JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.ID1 = t2.ID
JOIN Table2 t3 ON t1.ID2 = t3.ID
JOIN Table2 t4 ON t1.ID3 = t4.ID
JOIN Table2 t5 ON t1.ID4 = t5.ID
```

Comment: Thanks! it works in principle. I have to modify the syntax to: 

`SELECT T1.KEYID, T2.TERM AS TERM_ID1, T3.TERM AS TERM_ID2, T4.TERM AS TERM_ID3, T5.TERM AS TERM_ID4
FROM (((TABLE1 AS T1
INNER JOIN TABLE2 AS T2 ON T1.ID1=T2.ID)
INNER JOIN TABLE2 AS T3 ON T1.ID2=T3.ID)
INNER JOIN TABLE2 AS T4 ON T1.ID3=T4.ID)
INNER JOIN TABLE2 AS T5 ON T1.ID4=T5.ID`

Comment: @user2641103 whatever gets it working for you. I can't see that the parenthesis are necessary but if it's resolved the issue then go for it.

Comment: I was testing it with MS Access SQL editor and without the parentheses it was giving a syntax error message. It can be a driver flavour issue.